# Finding children that begin with

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to locate only children that begin with the text "EPCF" from my XML.

Here is the code I have today:

```
$(xml).find('Cat[name="' + catname + '"]').children("EPCF_1_1").each(function() {
```

This does indeed return only EPCF_1_1

My question is how do I return anything that *begins with* EPCF

I have tried

```
$(xml).find('Cat[name="' + catname + '"]').children().filter(':contains(EPCF)').each(function() {
```

with no luck and

```
$(xml).find('Cat[name="' + catname + '"]').children().filter(':contains("EPCF")').each(function() {
```

also with no luck - neither return errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$(xml).find('Cat[name^="' + catname + '"]')...
```

Comment: That was the tip that did it - working result:   $(xml).find('Cat[name="' + catname + '"]').children('[name^="EPCF"]').each(function() {

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the contents of each XML child node and test that it starts with EPCF:

```
epcfNodes = $(xml).find('Cat[name="' + catname + '"]')
                  .children()
                  .filter(function(i, v){
                      return /^EPCF/.test($(v).contents()[0].data);
                  });
```

### [See basic demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tgkRE/)